# When making an altcoin copy of Bitcoin, where should one start?

Tags: altcoin-development

In attempting to create a clone, a few things have to be considered... things like block time, reward, etc are often changed. What other things should be considered when messing with the source code?

Comment: Number of confirms for accepting mature coins from mining and transacting. Very few people understand that waiting for 6 confirms on the Bitcoin network is not equal to waiting for 6 confirms in Litecoin, for example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should study the current alt-coins world:

- [en.bitcoin.it: List of alternative cryptocurrencies](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_alternative_cryptocurrencies)
- [bitcointalk.org: List of all cryptocoins](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=134179.0)

The most interesting alt-coins today on my sight are:

- [Quarkcoin (QRK)](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=260031.0) blake, bmw, groestl, jh, keccak, skein
- [Primecoin (XPM)](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=245953.0) `First non-hashcash proof-of-work in cryptocurrency, pure prime number based proof-of-work`
- [Litecoin (LTC)](https://litecoin.org/) scrypt

The fastest way to understand what **must** be changed is take a source `bitcoin-0.6.3-linux.tar.gz` and source of `litecoin 60300`.

Thereafter, extract both archives into two directories and simply `diff -rHvn bitcoin litecoin`.

Change the names of configuration files, number of ports, etc... And change the hash function, if you wish.

You surely will meet two common troubles:

- **Kill network by difficulty.** Someone may come to your network with >50% of power, increase the difficulty and then disappear. After that, your network participants would found next block with **BIG delay**, which will break the stability of transactions, etc...
- **ASIC miner.** Today, any gamer with a TOP video card can't mine, in the top pool, not even **ONE Bitcoin** for **years**, because of ASIC miners. What to say about a finding of block, solo-mining.

First can be solved, I think, by reinventing dependence on the difficulty by adding a dependency on ***Time***. For example:

> Next block must be with 10 zeroes in the start, but after one minute the
>   number of zeroes would be decreased by one, at the second minute decrease
>   this doorstep again, etc...

Second, the ASIC miner, may be conquered by the really hard hash algorithm. Look at the **QRK**: probably nobody will draw such circuit while the game isn't worth the candles. But here you'll meet next attack: someone may analyze the cascade of hashes and find a much easiest way to getting blocks.

---

You can observe the world of alt-coins and you will realize that nobody needs your **new** coin. There are about 30 very active alt-coins and about 100 in incipience. I predict: "In the next year this numbers would be multiplied by **10**!": 300 active alt-coins with various difference from bitcoin and 1000 full clones, differing only by labels.

You could blow up the market with **super innovation**.

One of the most interesting and costly thing is traceability of money, on my sight. E.g. Look at [zerocoin](http://zerocoin.org/).

The second is a dying of mining. The market of bitcoin might plop in.

---

**Edit:** Also, there is [rippled/xrp](https://ripple.com/guide/), sometimes ago it has become opensource.

- https://github.com/ripple/rippled/
- https://ripple.com/wiki/Introduction_to_Ripple_for_Bitcoiners

Also, look at granpa of ripple:

- https://classic.ripplepay.com/login/

One day, surely, there will appear a child of bitcoin and ripple. Kind of crypto-money-mutant.

---

`I leave here a little space for the future to add more interesting questions and answers.`

Comment: How do I get the `litecoin 60300` source?

Comment: Something like: `cd /usr/src; git clone https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin; cd litecoin; git rebase 3aaa7ba5d05ff7ec35e2cd704e1e1b3da58b70b4;`. You should download full bitcoin's and litecoin's gits.

Comment: Where did you come up with `3aaa7ba5d05ff7ec35e2cd704e1e1b3da58b70b4`?

Comment: When you clone full litecoin's git repository,  you could check the log `git log`, there is record from Date: Fri Jun 29 13:42:04 2012 -0700: `Change version to 0.6.3`, thereafter going a couple of fixes. My current version of git for experiments with clones is: Date: Sun Apr 14 01:50:46 2013 -0700: with last log record: `Do not warn about obsolete version.`. It looks like a complete litecoin v.60300. Just try to rebase here and compare with bitcoin 0.6.3, you'll see that there is no so many differences between ltc and btc.

Comment: Please add a reference to Nxt ( www.thenxtcoin.com ), 2nd crypto-currency whose code doesn't descend from Bitcoin. It's an interesting concept: all coins have been pre-mined and no more will ever be, you earn interest just by holding some Nxt (receiving a share of the transaction fees paid by others) which is proportional to how many Nxt coins you have.